# Using lme with a fixed beta (slope), and estimating the intercept only

Tags: regression, lme4-nlme

```
lme.1.combo <- lme(ComboRate ~ p_w, random = ~1 | Rat,data=x)
```

The line above will return a fitted intercept term, and a fitted beta (slope) term given these variables (allowing for random intercepts for each rat).

What I would like to do, is run the same regression, but with a FIXED slope. That is, if I keep the slope at a given value, what is the best fitting intercept going to be? So my output would be the best intercept value, given the slope value I assigned.

Is there a way to do this using `lme` or any other function in R?

Answer (score 8):

Yes. If you know that the slope is, for example, 1.5, then you just subtract `1.5 * p_w` from the outcome and refit the model with just the intercept term. So, in your example:

```
x$ComboRate.adj <- x$ComboRate - 1.5 * x$p_w
lme.2.combo <- lme(ComboRate.adj ~ 1, random = ~1 | Rat,data=x)
```

This is the same as using an offset in your model.

To check that this works, first try using the actual slope estimate you got from the `lme.1.combo` model to make sure you get the same intercept estimate from the offset model.